# Provide CA chain for my API: should I include all certs in chain?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, rest, ssl, https

Good day!

I'm developing REST-like API which is accessible via HTTPS. My certificate is issued by the CA and has intermediate certificates (3 levels to my cert: AddTrust -> Comodo -> EssentialSSL -> my cert).

I'd like to provide certificate chain with my .NET and PHP SDK for users of my API like Facebook does:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

I've created similar text file by ordering my certificates one by one and it works for command-line curl and PHP curl library.

But it works when I have only **one** root certificate (AddTrust in my case).

Should I bundle all certificates in chain with my SDK or just one root certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***need*** to bundle any certificates you don't expect users to have. If you are missing an intermediate certificate in the chain, all certificates below that will be invalid.

Your certificate was issued by EssentialSSL; without EssentialSSL's intermediate certificate, the system has no way of knowing that your certificate is valid, or that it ultimately traces back to AddTrust. For example, I have certificates already installed for AddTrust and Comodo, but not EssentialSSL, so my system would not consider your certificate trusted.

What exactly do you mean when you say "it works when I have only one root certificate"? You *always* have only one root certificate in a chain, by definition; the rest are intermediate certificates that were issued by someone higher up. Can you be more specific as to what problem you're actually having?

Comment: First I really think that I need full chain, so here comes a question. When I say "it works when I have only one root certificate" it means that when I supply full chain for curl and require SSL check it works the same way when I just supply only one top-level root cert.

Comment: Are you testing this on a machine other than your development machine? If the intermediate certificates are installed into your local certificate store then you don't need the chain at all. You need to find a machine without the "EssentialSSL" certificate installed to verify that your certificate chain is being properly loaded.

Comment: The command-line curl on Windows and curl library in php do not have *any certs* (even CA certs like browsers) by default.

Comment: checked with win32 build of wget -- it doesn't have any CA certs and requires to specify `--ca-certificate` option. I can access my HTTPS secured pages with full chain or just top-leve cert.